# How to use Extended Choice Parameter plugin with checkbox?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, extended-choice-parameter

I am using extended choice parameter plugin. I have to run specific/all components using checkbox or any other method. Here I was able to build specific component, but its failing when I build two or more components. here is the configuration that I am using. Am I missing any configuration?

```
Extended choice parameter:
Name: Component
Description:
Basic Parameter Types:
Parameter Type: Checkbox
Number of visible items:5
Delimiter: ,
Choose source for value:
Value: aa,bb,cc
```

Comment: please share pipeline's groovy code